# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Issue

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am exporting a query to Excel in Access 2013.  This is the syntax that I am using for the export

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qryDataExport", strExportPath, True
```

The data transfers as it should, but one of the fields in the query is titled `Player #` and when exported to Excel this becomes `Player .`

How can I keep the `#` intact with the export?

Comment: Is the field name enclosed in square brackets within the query object you are exporting?

Comment: @ChristopherD.- yes it is a short text type in the table and in the query it is listed as [Player #]

Comment: Try post # 11 found here https://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/130867-csv-Export-not-keeping-number-sign-on-field-name by AndrewKKWalker.  I believe the issue is you are using a reserved symbol in the export  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?CorrelationId=1e80e7bd-52b9-4d39-84cb-883f5fabf7a9&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010030643

Comment: @user2676140 while your analysis of the problem is spot-on, that solution isn't (it creates a CSV file, not an xslx file). If you want to export to an .xslx in this way, you need to create a custom export function.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - so I would need to use a custom export function to take the query to excel?  Would a recordset work or since that is not a "custom" function that would give me the same output?

Comment: Yes, you can create a custom export function using recordsets. Give me a sec and I might even write one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to export stuff to an .xlsx file, without having to deal with the limitations of `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`

```vb
Public Sub CustomExcelExport(QueryOrTableOrSQL As String, FileLocation As String)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(QueryOrTableOrSQL)
    excelApp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim colNo As Long: colNo = 1
    Dim rowNo As Long: rowNo = 1
    Dim fld As Variant

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        excelApp.Cells(rowNo, colNo) = fld.Name
        colNo = colNo + 1
    Next fld
    Do While Not rs.EOF
       colNo = 1
       rowNo = rowNo + 1
       For Each fld In rs.Fields
            excelApp.Cells(rowNo, colNo) = fld.Value
            colNo = colNo + 1
       Next fld
       rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileLocation, 51 'xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    excelApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Call it: `CustomExcelExport "qryDataExport", strExportPath`

Comment: I just moved the syntax over to my production database and it is hitting the line Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(QueryOrTableOrSQL) then leaving the procedure?  So no export is actually occuring. - and it is Excel 2013 if that makes a diff.

Comment: Is your query actually returning rows? That would happen if your query returned 0 rows and 0 fields.

Comment: It is returning rows - but it does seem one field has error ed bc it is asking for me to input a value.  Could that be the culprit?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work on parameterized queries (nor does `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` for that matter). You can adapt it to use a `QueryDef` and parameters, and use a `ParamArray` to send the parameters to the query, or you can just fix your query.

Comment: Yeah - I removed those fields and the query is executing as it should, now the procedure above gives me Run-time error '13':
Type Mismatch

Comment: There is only 1 row returned in the query that is throwing the error.  If I run the query manually it reutns data as expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158341/discussion-between-erik-von-asmuth-and-bellhopbydayametuercoderbynigh).

Answer (score 2):

While issue is reproducible with `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`, consider [DoCmd.OutputTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-outputto-method-access) which retains formatting of query. The former method may focus more on spreadseet formatting.

And in fact, `DoCmd.OutputTo` looks to be the automated version of the External Data \ Excel Export ribbon method (selecting to keep all formatting):

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryDataExport", acFormatXLSX, strExportPath
```